# MAMP/WordPress extraordinarily slow

Tags: wordpress, localhost, mamp

I'm not entirely sure when it happened, but suddenly all my locally-hosted WordPress sites are crazy slow (saving a page takes ~1-2 minutes). As soon as I move it to any external host, they're once again lightning quick, leading me to believe it's nothing to do with the WordPress site itself.

I realise this is quite a vague question, but how can I debug this? There's a good 40 or so sites hosted on MAMP, but I didn't think extra sites would slow it down if they weren't actively in use.

Comment: This is not a solution, but maybe a temporary fix. While looking for solutions myself and not finding any, I used MAMP's "check database", "repair database" function to try to see if that would smooth out the kinks. It seemed to help. So if you haven't fixed your problem, this might help.